# What Is the Different Between Single Nipple, Double Nipple, and Pipe Nipple

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

I just work on the engineering company that specialize in water piping. I am confuse about the term of nipple. What is the different between Single Nipple, Double Nipple, and Pipe Nipple? 
Hope somebody can help.
Thanks

Comment: So you work for a company specialising in water piping and no one there can tell you ....

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy:

Single nipple: One end with threads (grooves): [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=single+nipple&tbm=isch) (NSFW, due to unintended results)

Double nipple: Both ends with threads (grooves): [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+nipple&tbm=isch) (NSFW, due to unintended results)

And pipe nipples are like double nipples: [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=pipe+nipple&oq=pipe+nipple&tbm=isch)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But you mean for double nipple they have a bolt in the middle between the groove?

Comment: It looks so according to the photos.